# The referenced fallback queue must be an Omni-Channel queue Error

Tags: servicecloud, omnichannel, queue

Can anyone tell what is the meaning of this error?

"The referenced fallback queue must be an Omni-Channel queue This Route Work invocable action did not create a valid Pending Service Routing."

I have two sandbox with both having the same routing configuration, queue and flow. Sandbox A is fine and working but the flow in Sandbox B recieves the said error when I debug it. Is there settings or other configuration I missed? Thanks in advance!

[image]